# CREATE TABLE com coluna derivada PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Saudações a todos, estou aprendendo SQL recentemente e me encontrei com este problema dentro de uma base de dados que trouxe da internet para fazer alguns exercícios, porém estou encontrando um erro de expressão ao tentar criar a tabela abaixo:

```
**CREATE TABLE Actors(
ActorID BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
FamilyName nvarchar(100) NULL,
FullName AS (FirstName+isnull(' '+FamilyName,'')),
DoB datetime NULL,
DoD datetime NULL,
Gender nvarchar(20) NULL)**
```

O erro está sendo especificamente na expressão "FullName AS ...", o que há de errado com essa sentença?

Comment: Veja a  documentação "To create a generated column, use the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause in CREATE TABLE" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: FullName GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FirstName||' '||COALESCE(FamilyName, '')), tente assim

Comment: Muito obrigado @Motta, fiz as modificações e funcionou perfeitamente. Percebi que o erro se deu por conta na diferença de operadores entre o código que obtive e o usado no postgres, você sabe se existe alguma ferramenta que facilite essas integrações entre os diferentes DBs em SQL encontrados na internet hoje?

Comment: Não , não sei mas deve existir.

Comment: Entendi, de todo modo muito obrigado!